# Execute command as Normal user

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, iis-8, appcmd

I am using IIS 8 in my machine.
I want to execute the appcmd command in command prompt as **Normal user**. 
While executing this command I got the error as below,

```
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe list wp
```

I get this error message:

> The WAS service is not available - try starting the service first.

It works if I open the command prompt as administrator.

How can I achieve this as normal user?

Is there a way to get the application pool name of a worker process from C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

Appcmd is not intended for non-admin use:

> Appcmd.exe is intended for local management of the Web server [...]
>   and requires the user to have administrative privileges when using it.
>   If you require remote management or the ability to configure the Web
>   server without being an administrator on the server, you need to use
>   the remote delegation support that IIS Manager provides.

from *Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0 Resource Kit* by
Volodarsky et al., Microsoft Press (2008).

To solve your problem, you will probably be interested to investigate the remote delegation features they mention.